# Sqlite Insert or Update

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanted to update my existing table with new values but some of them are fresh. I have written code for updating the table, but how can I do both operations(update & insert) simultaneously.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? And add some of your code to your question? If I understand correctly, you need to update data if exist in database, else, insert new record.

Comment: @Mystic. Yeah that is what I want.
I got this query "INSERT OR REPLACE". Can I go with this..?

Comment: @Livin where is your code ?

Comment: @GrlsHu
String updationItem = "UPDATE bill_record SET ocr_store='" + ocr_store+ "'," + "ocr_amount='" + ocr_amount + "' WHERE _id=" + _id
+ " AND receipt_key=" + receipt_key + "";  DatabaseHelper.getInstance(mCtx).executeDMLQuery(updationItem);

Here if _id is not in the table, then I need to insert it as a new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use replace() method in SQLiteDatabase. Its simply insert a new row if no row with same key is not exists in database. Otherwise it replaces the existing row.. Its simple than other ways.. For more info refer the documentation..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String username="xyzName";
Cursor cur_user = my_db.rawQuery("SELECT _id from user_info where user_name ='"
                                    + username + "'", null);
if (cur_user.getCount() > 0) {

    // User exists. Update information in database.
    ContentValues cvUserInfo = new ContentValues();
    cvUserInfo.put("status", status_id);
    String whereClause = "user_name = '" + username + "'";
    try {
        my_db.update("user_info", cvUserInfo, whereClause, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {

    // Insert the information in database.

    ContentValues cvUserInfo = new ContentValues();
    cvUserInfo.put("status", status_id);
    cvUserInfo.put("user_name", username);
    my_db.insert("user_info", null, cvUserInfo);
}
```

You will need to have one column except id, on which you can check. I had user name as a unique column to check for existing record.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. But I believe this will consume some time to complete my task, since I'm running web service with large data this code will take some time.